# Google Fit API for Android

Tags: android, flutter, google-fit

## Google Fit and Flutter

I am following this documentation from Google:
[Google Fit](https://developers.google.com/fit/android/get-started)

I don't understand step 5. I am not an Android developer and I have no idea where to locate the code. [Step 5](https://developers.google.com/fit/android/get-started#step_5_connect_to_the_fitness_service)

For example, it says:
 Before you can invoke methods from the Google Fit APIs, you must connect to one or more of the following API clients, which are part of Google Play services:

- Sensors Client
- Recording Client
- History Client
- Sessions Client
- Goals Client
- BLE Client
- Config Client

Now, I try to connect the first one [SensorsClient](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/fitness/SensorsClient)

But I don't know where to locate the code, which file? I am a flutter developer and I need help in step 5.

**build.grandle**

```xml
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-fitness:18.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:17.0.0'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
}
```

Comment: The code to make the connection request is mentioned in the link that you have mentioned in your description. https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/fitness/SensorsClient . Are you looking for anything else apart from the code to get the access.

Comment: I have no idea to connect the sensors, the documentation is made for Android Developers not for Flutter Developers so what I don't understand is how to connect the sensors, which file I have to include the code?

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/sensors

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use Google Fit [Rest Api](https://developers.google.com/fit/rest) in Flutter.

Google manages the data through data sources. To see all the data sources:

https://www.googleapis.com/fitness/v1/users/me/dataSources

To get Number of Steps:
https://www.googleapis.com/fitness/v1/users/me/dataset:aggregate
Request body:

```
{    
    "aggregateBy" : [{    
        "dataSourceId": "derived:com.google.step_count.delta:com.google.android.gms:estimated_steps"    
    }],    
    "bucketByTime": { "durationMillis": 86400000 }, // This is 24 hours    
    "startTimeMillis": 1546210381932,   // Start time    
    "endTimeMillis": 1547210381932  // End Time    
}
```

You can use [fitKit](https://pub.dev/packages/fit_kit) which is Flutter plugin for reading health and fitness data. Wraps HealthKit on iOS and GoogleFit on Android.

```
    import 'package:fit_kit/fit_kit.dart';

void read() async {
  final results = await FitKit.read(
    DataType.HEART_RATE,
    dateFrom: DateTime.now().subtract(Duration(days: 5)),
    dateTo: DateTime.now(),
  );
}

void readLast() async {
  final result = await FitKit.readLast(DataType.HEIGHT);
}

void readAll() async {
  if (await FitKit.requestPermissions(DataType.values)) {
    for (DataType type in DataType.values) {
      final results = await FitKit.read(
        type,
        dateFrom: DateTime.now().subtract(Duration(days: 5)),
        dateTo: DateTime.now(),
      );
    }
  }
}
```

***If you are writing custom platform-specific code***

Before you can invoke methods from the Google Fit APIs, you must connect to one or more of the following API clients, which are part of Google Play services:

1. ***Sensors Client :*** Client which exposes different sources of fitness data in local and connected devices, and delivers live events to
   listeners.
2. ***Recording Client :*** Client which enables low-power, always-on background collection of sensor data into the Google Fit store.
3. ***History Client :*** Client for inserting, deleting, and reading data in Google Fit.
4. ***Sessions Client :*** Client for creating and managing sessions of user activity in Google Fit.
5. ***Goals Client :*** Client for reading fitness Goals created by users in Google Fit. BLE Client
6. ***Config Client :*** Client for accessing custom data types and settings in Google Fit.

You must connect one of above.

```
    DataReadRequest readRequest = new DataReadRequest.Builder()
                .aggregate(DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA, DataType.AGGREGATE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA)
                .setTimeRange(startTime, endTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .bucketByTime(1, TimeUnit.DAYS)
                .enableServerQueries()
                .build();
// History Client 
        Fitness.getHistoryClient(this, GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this))
                .readData(readRequest)
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DataReadResponse>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(DataReadResponse dataReadResponse) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "onSuccess()");
                    }
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "onFailure()", e);
                    }
                })
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DataReadResponse>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DataReadResponse> task) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "onComplete()");
                    }
                });
```

Example for getting Heart Rate from History Client:

```
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;

import android.Manifest;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.Auth;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignIn;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInResult;
import com.google.android.gms.fitness.Fitness;
import com.google.android.gms.fitness.FitnessOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.fitness.data.Bucket;
import com.google.android.gms.fitness.data.DataPoint;
import com.google.android.gms.fitness.data.DataSet;
import com.google.android.gms.fitness.data.DataType;
import com.google.android.gms.fitness.data.Field;
import com.google.android.gms.fitness.request.DataReadRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.fitness.result.DataReadResponse;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;


import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class googleFitData extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "googleFitData";
    private static final int GOOGLE_FIT_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE = 2;
    private static final int PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION = 3;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_smart_wacth);


        String[] PERMISSIONS = {
                Manifest.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION
        };


        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION)
                    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                        PERMISSIONS,
                        PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION);
            }
        } else {
            googleSignin();

        }


    }

    public void googleSignin() {
        FitnessOptions fitnessOptions = FitnessOptions.builder()
                .addDataType(DataType.TYPE_HEART_RATE_BPM, FitnessOptions.ACCESS_READ)
                .build();
        if (!GoogleSignIn.hasPermissions(GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this), fitnessOptions)) {
            GoogleSignIn.requestPermissions(
                    this, // your activity
                    GOOGLE_FIT_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE,
                    GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this),
                    fitnessOptions);
        } else {
            accessGoogleFit();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            if (GOOGLE_FIT_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE == requestCode) {

                accessGoogleFit();
            }
            if (PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION == requestCode) {

                accessGoogleFit();
            }
        } else {
            GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);

        }

    }

    private void accessGoogleFit() {
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTime(new Date());
        long endTime = cal.getTimeInMillis();
        cal.add(Calendar.YEAR, -1);
        long startTime = cal.getTimeInMillis();


        DataReadRequest readRequest = new DataReadRequest.Builder()
                .read(DataType.TYPE_HEART_RATE_BPM)
                .setTimeRange(startTime, endTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .bucketByTime(365, TimeUnit.DAYS)
                .build();


        Fitness.getHistoryClient(this, GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this))
                .readData(readRequest)
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DataReadResponse>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(DataReadResponse dataReadResponse) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "onSuccess()");

                        for (Bucket bucket : dataReadResponse.getBuckets()) {
                            Log.e("History", "Data returned for Data type: " + bucket.getDataSets());

                            List<DataSet> dataSets = bucket.getDataSets();
                            for (DataSet dataSet : dataSets) {
                                showDataSet(dataSet);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "onFailure()", e);
                    }
                })
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DataReadResponse>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DataReadResponse> task) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "onComplete()");
                    }
                });
    }

    private void showDataSet(DataSet dataSet) {
        DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat.getDateInstance();
        DateFormat timeFormat = DateFormat.getTimeInstance();

        for (DataPoint dp : dataSet.getDataPoints()) {
            Log.e("History", "Data point:");
            Log.e("History", "\tType: " + dp.getDataType().getName());
            Log.e("History", "\tStart: " + dateFormat.format(dp.getStartTime(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)) + " " + timeFormat.format(dp.getStartTime(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)));
            Log.e("History", "\tEnd: " + dateFormat.format(dp.getEndTime(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)) + " " + timeFormat.format(dp.getStartTime(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)));
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            cal.setTime(new Date());


                for (Field field : dp.getDataType().getFields()) {

                    Log.e("History", "\tField: " + field.getName() +
                            " Value: " + dp.getValue(field));

                }




        }
    }


}
```

Comment: Where is this code, which file? Android project? MainFile? DataReadRequest readRequest = new DataReadRequest.Builder() .... Tis is my problem where can I locate the code above? It's because I am not a Android Developer.

Comment: I am working on Flutter, I have no idea about Android native, that's why I can't understand the step 5 on the doc.

Comment: Check tha answer i have added example

Comment: Read further details about each client : https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/fitness/Fitness

Comment: @John so in order to use "DataType.TYPE_HEART_RATE_BPM" do we need to get the app verified by google?

Comment: No i used it without google app verification